# Run Core Animation Instruments from Terminal

Tags: xcode, terminal, core-animation, instruments, frame-rate

How can I capture the FPS user Xcode Instruments "Core Animation" template?

This is what I have tried

```
instruments -t "Core Animation" -w "eb6ddacthisismydeviceidasdfasdfasdfasdb22" MyApp.app
```

When I run this it creates a trace file but it does not capture any FPS (frames per second).  Ideally I would like to capture frames per second with a 1/10th of a second sample rate.

Comment: Do you try to use the simulator or a physical device? If simulator: code animation doesn't work with the simulator. If device: are you sure this is the right uuid? Try adding the flag -v for verbose. Does it work directly from xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does capture FPS, but in order to visualize it **Instruments** must have a target applied.

Save a trace: (I added verbose `-v` and time limit 40sec `-l 40000`)

```
instruments -t "Core Animation" -D ~/Desktop/YourTraceFileName.trace -w "eb6ddacthisismydeviceidasdfasdfasdfasdb22" -v -l 40000 YourApp.app
```

Open the trace file with Instruments: You'll see a message displaying that there is no device currently online.

[image]

Select your iPhone/iPad and your `YourApp.app - AppID` in the Installed Apps section, as Target.

[image]

Enable **Select statistics to list** `Frames Per Second` and **Statistics to Observe** `Frames Per Second`

[image]